# Get object's parameter with another parameter that is passed in method - Java

Tags: java, oop, parameters

I've created 4 charater objects with 4 parameters, which includes id. How can I access another parameter of object with one of its constructor parameters? For example, I want to create a method which will take id as a parameter and with that id, I want to specify on which character is user talking about, so I can get that specific character's parameters(Name etc).

**character objects**

```
    Character warrior = new Character("Warrior", 60, 15+rn.nextInt(5), 1); //name, health, damage, id
    Character skeleton = new Character("Skeleton", 90, 20+rn.nextInt(10), 2);
```

**Method I am trying to create**

```
public void spawnEnemy(int id){
    System.out.printf("%s appeared!", //get character's name with id);

}
```

Comment: [`java.util.Map<Integer, Character>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: Map<id,Character>

Comment: If the `id`s start at `0` and are guaranteed to be consecutive, you could also use a `Character[]` or a [`java.util.List<Character>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the `Character` class, you can give it a static, i.e. "global," `Map` to keep track of all instances. That way, client code doesn't have to worry about keeping track.

```
public class Character {

  // "Global" Map that tracks all Character instances by ID
  private static HashMap<Integer, Character> idToCharacter = new HashMap<>();

  // Fields, etc...

  public Character(String name, int health, int damage, int id) {
    // Set field values, etc...

    // Track this new Character
    idToCharacter.put(id);
  }

  // "Global" method for getting a Character by ID
  public static Character getCharacter(int id) {
    return idToCharacter.get(id);
  }

}
```

Then your client code simply calls `getCharacter`:

```
public void spawnEnemy(int id){
  System.out.printf("%s appeared!", Character.getCharacter(id).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all `Character` has a unique `id`, you can put them into a [`java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
HashMap<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
Character warrior = new Character("Warrior", 60, 15+rn.nextInt(5), 1);
map.put(1, warrior);
```

Then you can call `get` the `warrior` with `id 1`:

```
public void spawnEnemy(int id){
    System.out.printf("%s appeared!", map.get(id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't think of that!

Comment: minor optimization: `map.put(warrior.id(), warrior);` (assuming `Character` has a accessor-method `public int id() { return this.id; }`).

Comment: Yes it has getter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a global hashmap, or pass in a hashmap of `<Integer, Character>` to your method to quickly look up characters